# Move rows from DataTableA to DataTableB with update to Datarow

Tags: vb.net, listview, datatable, datarow

My application has two listviews L1 and L2 bounded each by datatables D1 and D2 respectively. Each Datatable has 5 columns in the same order and name with a primaryKey on Column1. I want to be able to edit the bounded datatables via row click interactions with L1 and L2 on the application; specifically, if a user clicks a row on L1 (fullrowselect = True):

1. Get the DataRow R1 from L1
2. Edit the PromaryKey value of R1 to be equal to 1 + Max(L2.col1) to ensure uniqueness - yields R1X
3. Delete the original R1 from L1
4. Add R1X into L2
5. Refresh both listviews to reflect the change

I am using the D2.Add(R1). Would this have anything to do with using D2.Rows.Add(R1X.ItemArray) instead?

The error I'm receiving is "This Row already belongs to another table". I am ensuring to attempt to delete the R1 from D1 first before inserting R1X into D2.

Comment: If this is WinForms, you should almost certainly be using `DataGridView` controls rather than `ListView` controls. You can then actually bind the data.  As for copying the data, look into the `ImportRow` method.

Comment: ok I'll have to investgate that method. How do you answer #2 above on the DataRow?

Comment: Let your database take care of Primary Key with identity/auto number field. Don't roll your own. You will have problems in a multi-user environment.

Comment: Thanks Mary. My program is designed to take in a file of raw data to be worked with within the application. There is no database interaction in the back end; oly interactions with D1 and D2.

Comment: Ok... Mary, I have constructed some data modelling before import to my application to guarantee that the primary keys in both D1 and D2 will be distinct. I did this by applying a 'series' to the key D1 series starts at 1,000,000 and D2 series starts at 2,000,000. This eliminates the need for #2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE:

Using ImportRow worked perfect as well as utilizing the database to scheme the primary keys such that there would be no chance of duplication then the following code works:

```
Dim HostRow As DataRow = D2.Rows.Find(SomeId)
        'Insert the dr into both target Tables
        D1.ImportRow(D2.Rows.Find(SomeId))
        'Delete the reference record from the host table
        D2.Rows.Remove(HostRow)
```

Thank you Everyone.